# How to design a router so URLs can load multiple models?

Tags: ember.js

I apologize in advance that I do not know exactly how to phrase this question.

I want to follow Tom Dale's advice* and stop breaking the web. In my case, I am building something that looks like Tweetdeck -- an application that can open an arbitrary number of columns. My problem is, I look at the Ember docs for [dynamic segments](http://emberjs.com/guides/routing/defining-your-routes/#toc_dynamic-segments), and I cannot figure out how to make the conceptual leap from a single model to multiple simultaneous models.

Instead of:

`http://localhost/columns/1`

I want to say something like:

`http://localhost/columns/1,34,54`

Where the numbers correspond to an arbitrary, variable-length *list* of models.

To be clear, I do not think I am asking about nested resources (like `:year/:month/:day`). Nor do I think I am asking about [query parameters](http://emberjs.com/guides/routing/query-params/), which I understand to be more geared toward disposable properties on the controller.

I don't know if there is a term for what I am looking for, which makes me wonder if I'm approaching this problem the wrong way. On the other hand, I can think of a few other analogies: Opening multiple simultaneous emails, diffing two or more documents, manipulating multiple playlists, etc. I'm not sure how to proceed.

*www.youtube.com/watch?v=OSEXpsVcTxI

Answer (score 1, accepted):

generally a dynamic slug refers to a single object, but there is no constraint, you'll just have to override some things (which is common) and have to do some transitioning manually (it'll be a bit more work to setup link-to statements)

```
App.Router.map(function() {
  this.route('cow', {path:':ids'});
});

App.CowRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function(params) {
    return [
      {id:3, color:'green3'},
      {id:5, color:'green5'},
      {id:7, color:'green7'}
    ];
  },
  serialize: function(model){
      return {ids: model.getEach('id')}; 
  }
});
```

http://emberjs.jsbin.com/aHOrowec/1